# What can we say about the minimal polynomial over a field $\mathbb{F}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field. Suppose $A \in GL(m,\mathbb{F})$, i.e. $A$ is an $m \times m$ invertible matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$. Now let $A$ have order $n$.

What can we say about the minimal polynomial of $A$?

Answer (score 3):

It is because $A^n=I$, so $A$ is a root of $X^n-1$. The kernel of $F[X]\rightarrow Gl(m,F)$ defined by $P\rightarrow P(A)$ is an ideal which is principal since $F$ is a field, it is generated by the minimal polynomial $P_A$  of $A$ and it contains $X^n-1$, we deduce that $P_A$ divides $X^n-1$.

Comment: What kind of thing is your map $\mathbb F[X]\to GL(m,\mathbb F)$? In order to speak about its kernel being an _ideal_, it would need to be something like a _ring_ homomorphism, but $GL(m,\mathbb F)$ is not a ring, only a group.